# Select columns which contain a certain number in matrix

Tags: r, matrix, filtering

I have a matrix `A`:

```
1   0   2
1   3   1
```

I want to choose all columns which contain the number 1. My desired output:

```
1   2
1   1
```

Comment: Try `Filter(function(x) any(x ==1), A)`

Comment: @d.b Thanks for your help. I think we just need an additional comma right after the open bracket to return a matrix

Comment: @TuanDo if you have a matrix, then yes you need that extra comma in d.b's answer and akrun's answer won't work at all. If you have a data frame (as implied in your question, *"I have a df..."*) then both d.b's and akrun's code work fine as-is.

Comment: @Gregor actually I have a matrix, not df. Sorry for the mistake. I fixed it in the question.

Answer (score 2):

**DATA**

```
A = matrix(c(1, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1), nrow = 2)
A
#     [,1] [,2] [,3]
#[1,]    1    0    2
#[2,]    1    3    1
```

**1**

```
A[,colSums(A == 1, na.rm = TRUE) > 0, drop = FALSE]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    1    1
```

**2**

```
A[,apply(A, 2, function(x) any(x == 1)), drop = FALSE]
#     [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1    2
#[2,]    1    1
```